Are there established methods to describe moves on an indoor, top rope route?
Are there any (standard) ways to describe a sequence of moves on an indoor, top rope route? The simplest one would be to number all holds and list a sequence of moves, e.g.
LF1 (left foot on hold #1)
RH3 (right hand on hold #3)
...

The most intuitive one I came up with is an animation of a stick figure or a more realistic rendering of a climber with a picture of the route in the background.
Does anything like this exist in real world?

I do not know of any standards. Keep in mind, that it may not be enough to tell which hand moves to which hold. Many holds have multiple ways to grab them, and you would need to describe that as well. There is plenty of other important micro-beta. What are you trying to archive with that? I know that some people write down the beta for their projects, if that is your goal take whatever notation you find best

@Manziel Yes, there is a need to describe hold contact in more detail, e.g. LF4 heel hook. It may be even more difficult in pictorial representation. This is for my own use. I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something usable already exists.

Would such a description be useful for anybody but you? Would I, with a different body shape (and different strengths and weaknesses,) be able to use your description?

@Willeke Obviously, climbers with different body sizes and strengths could climb differently. Personally, I see it as a memory crutch on routes, which are at the edge or beyond my skill level, so I don't have to rediscover what took me many attempts to solve and perhaps record what didn't work. I try to climb with people of similar size and skills, so we can directly learn from each other.

There is definitely semi-standard lingo to describe foot/hand-holds and how to use them in terms of body position (including e.g. fingers). Semi-standard as while there's common terms, there's also often more terms than one for the same thing (e.g. regional differences). I thought there was a question on hold types already, but didn't find it. Imo this is the main component, once you have that any kind of list of list using that hold and usage lingo plus specifying which extremity (though I believe that's often obvious) would do to describe a route/sequence - not aware of any standards there.
